# std:upper_bound fails in class object. is there a straight-forward way to make it work?

Tags: c++

I have a data class, Data1, that contains a variable Label1. I have made a vector of the Data1, and that vector is ordered alphabetically from lowest to highest.  The class declaration is shown below.  I would like to use the std::upper_bound  to find out where to insert new values of Data1.Label1.  Is there a simple, straightforward way to use upper_bound in this instance?  My searches of this site have not come up with one.

```
class DataClass1
{
public:
    DataClass1(){};
    ~DataClass1(){};

    std::string Label1;
    int Val0;

private:

} Data1;
```

The following code fails on the `upper_bound(...)` function because it does not reference Label1.  I can find no way to drill down to `Data1.Label1`.  For example, entering `Data1.Label1.begin()` obviously does not work.  Seems there should be a simple solution and a general rule for this and other functions like `sort(...)`.

```
std::vector<string>::iterator it ;
it = std::upper_bound(Data1.begin(), Data1.end(), String_to_Find) ;
```

Comment: You can specify your own comparator. See overload #2 here : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: Your declaration shows `Data1` being an instance of `DataClass1`, yet the text of your question seems to be suggesting it is a `std::vector<DataClass1>`. And you expect `std::upper_bound` to return a `std::vector<string>::iterator`? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Start reading here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound - note the requirement for `operator<` or a custom comparator.

Comment: I have spent a lot of time analyzing the upper_bound(...) examples at cppreference.com and others.  Perhaps it is my newness to this part of c++ but those examples do not answer the specific question regarding a variable in a class object. Hence, the question posted here.

Comment: ^ This is ***precisely*** what should have been in your original post.